# PHP accessing private XML files without routing

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I'm creating a website that need a XML file for some data. The webpage will open it (but not showing it). How can it access that XML file without routing? This XML file is secret, so I don't want to put it in the public folder (the user can't access it, but the page can).
Also, I tried this:

```
$xmlParser = new DOMDocument();
$xmlParser->load("{{ link_to('resources\views\data.xml','Link') }}");
//...
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You want to load the XML file in controller action and pass it into view and use `storage_path()` to obtain the location, and place XML file in storage directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your XML file is in this directory

```
`storage/app/data.xml`
```

You can display the file as such

```
$pathToFile = storage_path('app/data.xml');
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

You can put this logic in a Controller for example and determine whether the request is authorised to access the file or not.

More information in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-responses)